# VSCode Snippets: Format File Name from my_file_name to MyFileName

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am creating custom snippets for flutter/dart. My goal is to pull the file name (TM_FILENAME_BASE) remove all of the underscores and convert it to PascalCase (or camelCase).

Here is a link to what I have learned so far regarding regex and vscode's snippets. 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

I have been able to remove the underscores nicely with the following code

```
    ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[\\_]/ /}
```

I can even make it all caps

```
    ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}
```

However, it seems that I cannot do two steps at a time. I am not familiar with regex, this is just me fiddling around with this for the last couple of days.

If anyone could help out a fellow programmer just trying make coding simpler, it would be really appreciated!

I expect the output of "my_file_name" to be "MyFileName".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as easy as that: `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe how easy it was!

Answer (score 0):

For the camelCase version you mentioned, you can use:

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/camelcase}/}`